# Code is not executing when i pass a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the problem that my code is not performing the ajax call when i pass a `search` parameter. I added several `console.log` to my code! So that you i hope you can easily comprhened my code:

```
icd: function(icd,id,search){
        if(!(typeof search === 'undefined')){
            var urls = "icd?search=" + search;
console.log("1");
        }else{
            if(icd == 2){
              var urls = "/icd/icd2/" + id;
            }if(icd == 3){
              var urls = "/icd/icd3/" + id;
            }
 console.log("2");
        }
 console.log("3");
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: SERVER + urls,
            headers: {"X-TOKEN": TOKEN},
            success: function(data,status,xhr){ 
 console.log("4");
                    var array = $.map(data['icd'], function (field, i) {
                        return '<tr data-link="'+ field.id +'"><td>' + field.nummer + '</td><td>' + field.bezeichnung + '</td></tr>';
                    });

                    $('#DiagnosenTable').html(array.join(''));  
                    $('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').html($('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{href: '#',text: 'Alle',click: function(){Diagnose.start()} })));
                    if(icd == 2){
                        $('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').append($('<li/>', {class: 'active',text: data['icd1'].bezeichnung}));
                    }
                    if(icd == 3){
                        $('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').append($('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{href: '#',text: data['icd1'].nummer,click: function(){Diagnose.icd(2,data['icd1'].id)} })));
                        $('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').append($('<li/>', {class: 'active',text: data['icd2'].bezeichnung}));
                    }
                    $('#DiagnosenTable tbody').eq(0).children('tr').each(function(){
                        $(this).click(function(){
                            if(icd == 2){
                                Diagnose.icd('3',$(this).attr('data-link'));
                            }else{
                                $('#inputCode').val($(this).children('td')[0].innerHTML);
                                $('#inputBez').val($(this).children('td')[1].innerHTML);
                                $('#TextEntry').val($(this).children('td')[0].innerHTML);
                            }
                        });
                    });                                     
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    ErrorHandler.connection(xhr,status,error);
console.log("5");
                    }
        });
console.log("6");


    }
```

When i first tried to execute my code, i noticed that when i pass a `search` parameter, the ajax call isnt performed (because `4` or `5` is not printed to the console)Here is a screenshot from my console:

[image]

I cant explain me why this happens! What do i wrong?

Comment: Where do you set `SERVER`?

Comment: @EdCottrell Global! The thing is that how i show in the image Diagnose.icd('2','2') is working but Diagnose.icd('','', value) not! Why?

Comment: I think epascarello's answer is correct, but you should verify that SERVER is actually set and contains what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these URLS is not like the other

```
var urls = "icd?search=" + search;
var urls = "/icd/icd2/" + id;
var urls = "/icd/icd3/" + id;
```

Do you see why the search URL does not work? It is different than the others. AKA: It is missing the a leading `/`.

```
var urls = "/icd?search=" + search;
            ^
```

Comment: So what does the console say when you look at the Ajax request [network tab]? How are you calling the function?

Comment: Sorry i had a code duplication and changed my code at the false location!